# .htaccess rule for language detection in subdirectory

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have an URL that is `https://www.myurl.com/subdir/language/login.php` .
The "language" parameter is not an existing subfolder. The folder structure is:

`root/subdir/.htaccess`

As you can see the .htaccess file is located in `https://www.myurl.com/subdir/.htaccess`

I would like to do a .htaccess Rewrite Rule in order to change the called uri:
`https://www.myurl.com/subdir/en/login` (without .php)
to:
`https://www.myurl.com/subdir/login.php?lng=en`

My current apporach is:

```
# MultiViews must be disabled for the rewrite to work
Options -MultiViews
# Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/

RewriteRule (en|de)(/login)$ login.php?lng=$1 [L]
```

But when I call the URI `https://www.myurl.com/subdir/en/login` I get an http error code `404`.

Comment: Your Test was successful, it throws a 500 internal server error.

Comment: Yes thats it! 
One more question, what if the scenario is all the same, but I would like to get the (en/de) in front of /subdir/ ? So the url would be https://www.myurl.com/en/subdir/login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes thats it! One more question, what if the scenario is all the same, but I would like to get the `(en/de)` in front of `/subdir/` ? So the url would be `myurl.com/en/subdir/login`:

In this case rule must be placed in site root .htaccess instead of `subdir/.htaccess` with this rule:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en|de)/(subdir/login)/?$ $2.php?lng=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```